# How do you taper values off to zero in a numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a very large array of 180000 columns, but for simplicity it looks something like this:

```
delta_v = [[3.4123 3.4213 3.4303 0.49377 0.49878 0.50381]]
```

What I want to do is to create a new 500x6 array, which will take each value and evenly increment down to a value of zero in the last row. I know how I'd do this if all values in the row were the same, but seeing as they're all different and would require different step sizes, I'm finding it a bit hard to figure out. So something that would look like this:

```
delt_var = [[3.4123 3.4213 3.4303 0.49377 0.49878 0.50381]
              ...     ...    ...    ...     ...     ...
            [  0       0      0      0       0       0   ]]
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply multiply all values to an array that decrement them evenly:

```
arr = np.vstack((delta_v, np.arange(0,1,1/499)[::-1][:,None]*delta_v))
```

stacking is due to the fact that in python, last index is excluded, so you might need to stack original array (or a row of 1s to np.arange) depending on number of rows you want.